# How can I search the copy/paste buffers of tmux?

Tags: tmux

When using tmux and hitting `prefix` + `=` I get the history of the buffers I copied previously. I've increased the number of copy buffers, I really need some way to search it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

As of tmux 2.6, this is now possible thanks to a rewrite of the `choose-*` commands, including `choose-buffer`.

Just open buffer list via `choose-buffer` (NOT `list-buffers`) then use `C-s` to search, and `n` to move to the next match. See the updated man page section on `choose-buffer` for more information.

Comment: Is there an option to do it in 2.1? it seems that when trying to install tmux on ubuntu (sudo apt-get install tmux) it installs 2.1 and not 2.6.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of an easy way to do this in earlier versions of tmux. Assuming you have the rights to do it, you could try building tmux from source. It's what I do on Ubuntu, and it's surprisingly easy as tmux has very few dependencies (only libevent and ncurses). Otherwise you may have to wait for Ubuntu to update its tmux version.